# bind datagrid to collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

how do I bind a DataGrid to a collection ? (e.g : List ).

i used this :

```
Datagrid dg = new Datagrid();
dg.DataSource = myCollection;
dg.DataBind();
```

but after this, the Datagrid still doesn't display the data from the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as you bind a datagrid to a DataTable/DataSet.  Your object properties will behave like column names when databinding.

```
DataGrid1.DataSource = myList;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> lst= new List<string>();

lst.Add("your string");

Datagrid dg = new Datagrid();
dg.DataSource=lst;
dg.DataBind();
```

disclaimer: I have not run this code, but this should give your a general idea

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your Datagrid object (dg) to your form.

```
this.Controls.Add(dg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `YourDataGrid.Datasource` to the instance name of the `List` and call
the `YourDataGrid.DataBind()` function.